# IOException - Access Denied Using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, ioexception, access-denied

I get the following IOException :

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
 at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:850)
 at zipUnzipper.main(zipUnzipper.java:41)
```

When trying to run the following piece of code :

```
public class zipUnzipper {
    public zipUnzipper() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Unzip to temp folder. Add all files to mFiles. Print names of all files in mFfiles.
        File file = new File("C:\\aZipFile.zip");
        String  filename = file.getName();
        String filePathName = new String();

        int o = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
            filename = filename.substring(0,o);

        try {      
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile (file.getAbsoluteFile());
                Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries();
                while(entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
                    System.out.println("Unzipping: " + zipEntry.getName());
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry));
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    filePathName = "C:\\TEMP\\"+filename+"\\";
                    File fileToWrite = new File(filePathName+ zipEntry.getName());
                    fileToWrite.mkdirs();
                    fileToWrite.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( fos , buffer.length );
                    int size;
                    while ((size = bis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                    }
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    bis.close();
                }
                zipFile.close();
                File folder = new File (filePathName);
                File [] mFiles = folder.listFiles();

                for (int x=0; x<mFiles.length; x++) {
                                System.out.println(mFiles[x].getAbsolutePath());
                        }
        } catch (ZipException ze) {
            ze.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

It seems to me that for some reason the JVM can't create a new file. The code runs perfectly well if the files already exist. Is there some kind of access file which dictates whether the JVM can create a new file or am I simply doing something wrong?

Any help is much appreciated :-)

I'm running Java 1.4 and have been testing in JDeveloper in Windows XP.

Comment: Does your Windows account have permissions to create files in that directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23697734/715269

Comment: Have you tried closing fileToWrite and then reopening it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that these calls step on each other:

```
  fileToWrite.mkdirs(); //creates a directory e.g. C:\temp\foo\x
  fileToWrite.createNewFile(); //attempts to create a file C:\temp\foo\x
```

The create operation fails because you just created a directory with the same name than the file you want to create.

What you want to do instead is:

`fileToWrite.getParentFile().mkdirs()`

And also, the call to `createNewFile()` is unnecessary.

Based on your code. The following "unzips" a zip file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Unzipper {
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException {
        final File file = new File(args[0]);
        final ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        final File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), zipFile.getName());

        if(!tmpDir.mkdir() && tmpDir.exists()) {
            System.err.println("Cannot create: " + tmpDir);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        for(final Enumeration entries = zipFile.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements();) {
            final ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Unzipping: " + zipEntry.getName());

            final InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);
            final File fileToWrite = new File(tmpDir, zipEntry.getName());
            final File folder = fileToWrite.getParentFile();
            if(!folder.mkdirs() && !folder.exists()) {
                System.err.println("Cannot create: " + folder);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if(!zipEntry.isDirectory()) {
                //No need to use buffered streams since we're doing our own buffering
                final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToWrite);
                int size;
                while ((size = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                }
                fos.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        zipFile.close();
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested it beyond the very basics.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `createNewFile()`? Just create the FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

It also could be that in context where you are launching the application you haven't access rights to the place where you are trying to create the file. Launch the app as admin or create the file in the project folder.