# Creating new files concurrently

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, file

To create a new, unique filename, I use the following code:

```
File file = new File(name);
synchronized (sync) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (file.exists()) {
        file = new File(name + " (" + (cnt++) + ")");
    }
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

Next, I use the file and delete it. 
When I do this in a multithreaded situation, I sometimes get exceptions on the `file.createNewFile()`:

```
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

The following code reproduces the problem (most of the times):

```
final int runs = 1000;
final int threads = 5;
final String name = "c:\\temp\\files\\file";
final byte[] bytes = getSomeBytes();
final Object sync = new Object();

ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
for (int thread = 0; thread < threads; thread++) {
    final String id = "Runnable " + thread;
    exec.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
                try {
                    File file = new File(name);
                    synchronized (sync) {
                        int cnt = 0;
                        while (file.exists()) {
                            file = new File(name + " (" + (cnt++) + ")");
                        }
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }

                    Files.write(file.toPath(), bytes);
                    file.delete();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.err.println(id + ": exception after " + i
                            + " runs: " + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(id + " finished fine");
        }
    });
}
exec.shutdown();
while (!exec.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

The method `getSomeBytes()` just generates an amount of bytes, the actual content is not important:

```
byte[] getSomeBytes() throws UnsupportedEncodingException,
        IOException {
    byte[] alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ1234567890\r\n"
            .getBytes("UTF-8");
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            baos.write(alphabet);
        }
        baos.flush();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

When I execute this code, it sometimes goes well but most of the times, it generates some exceptions like the output below for instance:

```
Runnable 1: exception after 235 runs: Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at test.CreateFilesTest$1.run(CreateFilesTest.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Runnable 4: exception after 316 runs: Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at test.CreateFilesTest$1.run(CreateFilesTest.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Runnable 2: exception after 327 runs: Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Access is denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
    at test.CreateFilesTest$1.run(CreateFilesTest.java:36)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Runnable 3 finished fine
Runnable 0 finished fine
```

Any ideas? I have tested on a Windows 8 machine with java 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0_31, both same results.

Not sure whether the problem is the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516472/file-createnewfile-randomly-fails), but it can be. Using multiple threads in the same process seems to be part of the problem to my opinion but I can't be sure about that, it's faster reproduced however.

Comment: `File.createTempFile()` may be a cleaner approach here, regardless of whether the file is actually intended to be temporary.

Comment: @Sneftel: I agree, however, the name of the file does matter so I can't use File.createTempFile here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that on Windows platform `createNewFile` may randomly fail if the file with the same name was just deleted even on single-threaded application. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10516472/4856258) for details. To fix your issue, you may try to ignore `IOException` from the `createNewFile` and continue. Something like this:

```
synchronized (sync) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (true) {
        try {
            if(file.createNewFile())
                break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // continue;
        }
        file = new File(name + " (" + (cnt++) + ")");
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to check `file.exists()` call as `createNewFile()` conveniently returns whether it created the file successfully.

Note that if you control all the temporary files you create and don't care about exact file name, usually there's no need to lock. You may just use global `AtomicLong` to get the next file name or append a thread ID to the file name.

Comment: Since the problem is probably caused by an external factor, I guess I'm gonna try/catch myself out of the problem in this case

Answer (score 0):

Your loop isn't fail-safe. There's a timing-window problem. It should be more like this:

```
while (!file.createNewFile()) {
        file = new File(name + " (" + (cnt++) + ")");
    }
```

Comment: Could you please be a little more verbose on what is "timing-window" in this synchronized section? Also your fixed code fails just in the same way as OPs code.

Comment: @TagirValeev There is a timing window between `exists()` and `createNewFile()` during which the file can be created by another thread. There is also a failure to check the result of `createNewFile()`. If the two-line loop I have posted here fails, there must be a platform problem with this method not working as advertised. There is in fact no difference between this loop and the code in your answer othe than the catch block. How do you explain that?

Comment: Please note that all the threads are synchronized on the same monitor, thus another thread cannot do this.

Comment: @TagirValeev So another *process* can create it. There's still a timing window problem.