# IOException at java.io.File.createNewFile();

Tags: java, serialization, filestream, ioexception

I do have some code for serialization which does not work. I have tried to insert both CanRead() and CanWrite() in if-statements which showed they did not have permissions to read and write. I have also tried to insert 'java.io.File.setReadable' and 'java.io.File.setWriteable to true but it still throws the error.

The code is as following:

```
public static void save(Object obj, String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File f = new File("c:/DatoChecker/" + filename);
    File dir = new File("c:/DatoChecker");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    f.setReadable(true);
    f.setWritable(true);
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    FileOutputStream op = null;
    ObjectOutputStream objectStream = null;
    op = new FileOutputStream(f);
    objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(op);
    objectStream.writeObject(obj);
    objectStream.close();
}

public static Object fetch(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    File f = new File("c:/DatoChecker" + filename);
    File dir = new File("c:/DatoChecker");
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();
    f.setReadable(true);
    f.setWritable(true);
    if(!f.exists())
    {
        f.createNewFile();
    }
    FileInputStream ip = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectStream = null;
    Object obj = null;
    ip = new FileInputStream(f);
    objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(ip);
    obj = objectStream.readObject();
    ip.close();
    objectStream.close();  
    return obj;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: access denied
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:947)
    at com.check.me.Serialization.fetch(Seralization.java:39)
    at com.check.me.GoodsList.load(GoodsList.java:82)
    at com.check.me.START.main(START.java:22)
```

The one for save is congruet from GoodsList (just save instead of load) and up but it is quite a bit longer below so I will leave it out for now.

Thanks for the help beforehand

Highace2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23697734/715269

Comment: @Gangnus as you may have noticed, this question has already been answered. And it was not something how it was created but in which scope it was designated. Basically pick the right directory.

Comment: The problem is, that it is repeated question. It had to be closed, commented, but not answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You state that you did *not* have permission to read or write. And, indeed, you get an error telling you that you don't have permission. You need to change the ACL on the directory in which you are creating the file, or pick a different directory.

Comment: I have now update my code (see first post) so creates another directory in the C:/-directory. Now it works with saving the files but not loading them. It still throws the same exception.

Comment: @Highace2 note that in the `fetch()` method the file name is missing a slash, it should be:
`File f = new File("c:/DatoChecker/" + fileName);`