# java application can create directories but cant create files in it

Tags: java

I've created a Minecraft launcher, and I want it to be able to download some mods automatically, the launcher can create all of the directories it needs, but can't actually download the JARs into the mods directory.

The message is always the same (Access denied)

Is there any way to fix this? I even tried downloading to the %temp% directory and moving the mods from there. It still gives me "Access denied".

The path is "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\.techette" -
and the mods directory is just a child of that.

Here is the code I have for downloading the file.

```
Request.Get(url).execute().saveContent(new File(downloadDir));
```

the library is apache fluent-hc im pretty sure

ive been sitting on this for about a week now, so i would appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: any chance the folder and file name are same? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20724720/4887159

Comment: no unfortunately not