# Receiving NumberFormatException error when trying to run my program

Tags: java

I asked this question earlier but was requested to add additional info and never got a response after that. Sorry ahead of time. I am not trying to spam the site or anything. I'm just looking for some assistance.

I am receiving the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 50" in the code below. And I am having a hard time solving it. Could anyone possibly shed some light on what it could be from? From my understanding it usually means the error is in line 3 and line 50 correct?

```
 package report.generator;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class ReportGenerator
 {


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\sprocketorders.txt"));
        String line;
        String element[] = new String[2];
        int   sum[] = new int[5];
        File file = new File ("C:\\sprocketordersreport.txt");

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            element = line.split(" ");

            switch(Integer.parseInt(element[0]))
            {
                case 1:
                    sum[0] = sum[0] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    sum[1] = sum[1] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    sum[2] = sum[2] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    sum[3] = sum[3] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    sum[4] = sum[4] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write("Spacely Sprockets\nTaking Sprockets into the Future\nSales Summary Report\nSprocket Number Total Quantity Sold\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
            bw.write((i + 1) + "\t" + sum[i] + "\n");

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally
    {
       try
        {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
            if (bw != null)
                bw.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
      }

  }
```

This program is to take an input from a text file and output the information in a report format.

EDIT: Here is the input file info. After looking at it, it looks like this may be where the problem is coming from. But I'm not entirely sure.

3 50

2 20

2 100

5 15

1 90

5 85

4 300

2 35

3 100

It's not formatting it exactly as it is in the text file. There are more spaces between the integers on the left and those on the right.

```
                        Spacely Sprockets
                 Taking Sprockets into the Future 
                      Sales Summary Report
    Sprocket Number                          Total Quantity Sold
         1                                           90
         2                                           155
         3                                           50
         4                                           300
         5                                           100
```

This is the output report that I am trying to get. Each number on the left is a sprocket number. The numbers on the right reflect the quantity sold of each sprocket.

This is the full exception when trying to run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3    50"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at report.generator.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:32)
```

http://m.uploadedit.com/b034/1398740135243.txt

Comment: What output do you expect for each line of input, and why? Also, that is your first line of input. Please post your entire exception, it will tell you which line in your source is throwing the Exception.

Comment: "3 50" isn't a number; it's **two** numbers. And that's what you're passing if you're getting that error.

Comment: And ... just caught your last paragraph. You're telling it to split on one, single space ... which isn't what you have in your file.

Comment: The Java authors must be crying. They put in all this time to have a useful and informative system of exceptions, but people don't even read them or consider them important enough to post with their coding questions...

Comment: To help you read the exception output, the exception is from line 65.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I have updated the original post with the entire exception.

Comment: @BrianRoach when I put the text file information into the question it closed the gap in the spaces. And yes "3   50" is two numbers. It is meant to mean 50 of sprocket 3 were sold. At least that's what that line in the text file says.

Comment: I also added a link at the end of the post that displays what is in the text file exactly as it should.

Comment: @user3485794 Are you you don't have *tabs* in that file? Split on `"\\t"` or even `"\\s+"` (the latter being "one or more whitespace chars" which includes tabs)

Comment: @BrianRoach If you look at the link I added as well at the end, it shows exactly what is in that text file.

Comment: From the exception output it looks like you _do_ have tabs in between 3 and 50. Or at least multiple spaces.

Comment: @Takendarkk sorry not 65, that is the line is numberformatexception. Line 32 is where his code failed.

Comment: @RobertSnyder But that is not where the exception came from. If you read my comment I said the exception came from line 65, which indeed it did.

Comment: @Takendarkk what am I missing at line 65? Any assistance would be great. I have been staring at this for some time now and am going crazy.

Comment: Thank you all for the help thus far.

Comment: Can you indicate which line #65 is?

Comment: @Takendarkk line 65 is: catch (IOException e)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
element = line.split(" ");
```

Comment: Where would this be added? Inside the while loop?

Comment: Wherever you have `element = line.split(" ");` put the other line right above it.

Comment: @Takendarkk Got it. Tried that. Got this exception instead now:

java.io.IOException: Access is denied
 at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1006)
 at report.generator.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:55)

Comment: 'Access is denied at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)' That's a new one for me, I pass the torch unto more experienced fellows for now.

Comment: @Takendarkk thanks for the help so far. I replied about about line 65. If there is any way for this to still be solved without adding     line = line.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " "); that would be great.

Comment: That particular line should not throw any exception. I'm still trying to figure out how it is possible.

Comment: @Takendarkk I'm sure you can see where my headache is coming from. I'm drawing a blank right now. Thank you.

Comment: @user3485794 As Takendarkk said, your exception is not related to the code above.

Comment: @user3485794 This exception seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602157/ioexception-access-denied-using-fileoutputstream

Answer (score 1):

The file you are reading has one element as "3 50".The character between 3 and 5 might be a whitespace or a special char.  Either delete/correct that line or handle any exceptions that you get while reading the rows

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to just use `+=` and a [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html); it works here regardless of the white space I put on the lines in the file -

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line); // On the line.
    String a = null;
    String b = null;
    if (st.hasMoreElements()) {
      a = st.nextToken();
      if (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        b = st.nextToken();
      }
    }
    if (a != null && b != null) {
      switch (Integer.parseInt(a.trim())) {
      case 1:
        sum[0] += Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
        break;
      case 2:
        sum[1] += Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
        break;
      case 3:
        sum[2] += Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
        break;
      case 4:
        sum[3] += Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
        break;
      case 5:
        sum[4] += Integer.parseInt(b.trim());
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program.

it has below problem

when you read new line using buffered reader actually you are getting the whole line content.

but when i checked your input file , its having one line empty between each line.

but buffer reader read line considers even empty line as a line and tries to parse it

but parsing empty line gives us definitely Number format exception.

so do a check before you split and process your line whether line is empty and if not empty go ahead.

This what i have added before spliting a line and proceeding further

```
if(!line.equals(""))
```

below is the complete program which is working fine for me now and let me know for any issues.

```
package com.kb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ParseIntDemo {


    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\sprocketorders.txt"));
            String line;
            String element[] = new String[2];
            int   sum[] = new int[5];
            File file = new File ("D:\\sprocketordersreport.txt");

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(!line.equals("")){
                element = line.split(" ");

                switch(Integer.parseInt(element[0]))
                {
                    case 1:
                        sum[0] = sum[0] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        sum[1] = sum[1] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        sum[2] = sum[2] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        sum[3] = sum[3] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        sum[4] = sum[4] + Integer.parseInt(element[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!file.exists())
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Spacely Sprockets\nTaking Sprockets into the Future\nSales Summary Report\nSprocket Number Total Quantity Sold\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++)
                 bw.write((i + 1) + "\t" + sum[i] + "\n");
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally
        {
           try
            {
                if (br != null)
                    br.close();
                if (bw != null)
                    bw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
          }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same NumberFormatException error with using your code

Comment: i can run this and getting the output as below, any special chars?                      Spacely Sprockets
Taking Sprockets into the Future
Sales Summary Report
Sprocket Number Total Quantity Sold
1 90
2 155
3 150
4 300
5 100

Comment: I'm not seeing anything different. I will try to run through it again. I even started a new project from scratch and got the same problem.

Comment: 902 1553 1504 3005 100..this is what has been written to my destination file. with your pre appended text... is that your expected o/p what i am getting ?

Comment: It has not solved it. I started a new program from scratch again and used your code exact other than the file location. I am not finding the issue. I still get the same error as I did before.

Comment: then mostly problem with your file content.. but i copied the file content from your question only..double check your current file content and posted file content if any special characters are added in your file by hidden any chance ?

Comment: I checked the file content and cannot find any special characters within the file. I have exactly what I linked in the original question.

Comment: Got any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: no problem here..i debugged it...do you have any space at the beginig in the input file ? if any prob will discuss on skype